# Can I activate mana abilities even if I don't need the mana?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Rule 605.3a says:

> A player may activate an activated mana ability **whenever he or she has priority**, whenever he or she is casting a spell or activating an ability that requires a mana payment, or whenever a rule or effect asks for a mana payment, even if it's in the middle of casting or resolving a spell or activating or resolving an ability.

Do I understand correctly that I can tap [Pheres-Band Tromper](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=378506) enchanted with [Karametra's Favor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=378497) for mana in my opponent's end step even if I do not need any of it? If it works I could trigger inspired every turn without the need for attacking. Some years ago, mana burn definitely would have prevented this kind of play.

Comment: For the record, it wouldn't have prevented this behavior. A lot of people would pay 1 life for a +1/+1 counter!

Comment: @corsiKa, But that penalty reduces the benefit of that combo effect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can activate a mana ability even if you do not plan to use the mana. This is often called *floating* mana. This means that yes, you can use Karametra's Favor to trigger an Inspired ability every turn. Since the Magic 2010 rules update, mana burn does not exist any more, so keeping this mana in your mana pool until the end of the phase has no downside.

Comment: What are other names for "floating mana"?

Comment: @Pacerier floating mana is the action of putting mana into your mana pool without using it immediately. Most players tap the mana they need right when they need it, tapping for mana puts the mana into your mana pool and then you spend from there.